# when scrollView is decelerating, touch detection is slow

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, touch

I have a dummy view which acts as a scrollview but propagates touch event to responder chain.
Basically, it handles a pan gesture.  (as seen on [WWDC 2012 scrollView session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/))
And passes tap event to responder chain.

```
[dummyView addGestureRecognizer:scrollView.panGestureRecogonizer];
```

It works great but, I want to detect touches faster when things are decelerating.

I can only detect the touch after the scrolling halts completely.

How should I detect the touch event while scrollview is decelerating?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the multiple touch property of your scrollview to true

```
    [dummyView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```